# How to help NDSolveValue handle the addition of another dependent variable in a set of reaction-diffusion equations

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, warning-messages, finite-element-method

I am trying to use `NDSolveValue` to solve a system of coupled reaction-diffusion equations in a 2D space (technically 3D cylindrical coordinates, but due to radial symmetry I only have to worry about coordinates $r$ and $z$). I have a simplified version of what I am trying to do below, but it is still a little complex, so if more detail is needed I can include it.

To summarize the system, I have one species "$P$" that can diffuse throughout the entire space (a "rectangular" region defined for $0\leq r\leq\infty$ and $0\leq z\leq H$ for some finite $H$), and then it can react with an immobile species "$pL$" that is only present within some strip above the $z=0$ plane $0\leq z\leq s<H$. This forms a complex "$P\cdot pL$" which then produces a final species "$L$" (which can diffuse, but for testing right now I have omitted its diffusion).

I am currently trying to put in one element at a time to make sure I have put in each part correctly. Everything works fine up until I try to put in species "$L$", which then gives me an error about a singular matrix in the differential equation solver.

---

**Working Code**

The mesh I am currently using to accentuate the reaction region (which is probably built in an inefficient way) is created by

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

dr = .01; (*Close to r = 0*)
rFar = 100.; (*To "approximate infinity*)
h = 5.;
s = 1.;

coords = Join[Table[{r, z}, {z, 0, 1.2*s, s/5}, {r, dr, rFar, (rFar - dr)/90}] //Flatten[#, 1] &, Table[{r, z}, {z, 1.2*s + (h - 1.2*s)/5, h, (h - 1.2*s)/5}, {r, dr,rFar, (rFar - dr)/90}] // Flatten[#, 1] &];

elems = Table[If[Mod[a, 91] == 0, Nothing, {a, a + 1, a + 92, a + 91}], {a,Length@coords - 92}];

meshD = ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> coords, "MeshElements" -> {QuadElement[elems]}];
```

Everything works fine if I include the production of "$L$" (given by terms with the production rate $k_c$) without actually keeping track of "$L$" in a differential equation. So the differential equations that work are given by:

```
pSource = (P0*k)/(2.*\[Pi]*\[Sigma]^2)*Exp[-((r - dr)^2/(2.*\[Sigma]^2)) - k*t]*(1 - Exp[-100.*t]);(*Gaussian protease source that turns on quickly and depletes slowly*)

diffeqP = D[P[r, z, t], t] - DP*Laplacian[P[r, z, t], {r, \[Theta], z}, "Cylindrical"] + kon*P[r, z, t]*pL[r, z, t] - (koff + kc)*PpL[r, z, t] == NeumannValue[pSource, z == 0];

diffeqpL = D[pL[r, z, t], t] == -kon*P[r, z, t]*pL[r, z, t] + koff*PpL[r, z, t];

diffeqPpL = D[PpL[r, z, t], t] == kon*P[r, z, t]*pL[r, z, t] - (koff + kc)*PpL[r, z, t];
```

Along with boundary/initial conditions:

```
(*Set concentration to 0 far away*)

condrFar = DirichletCondition[P[r, z, t] == 0, r == rFar];

(*Initial Conditions*)

initP = P[r, z, 0.] == 0.;

initpL = pL[r, z, 0.] == If[0 <= z <= s, pL0, 0.];

initPpL = PpL[r, z, 0.] == 0.;
```

With this code, a solution is obtained using `NDSolveValue`

```
params = {P0 -> 1000., k -> 5., \[Sigma] -> 20., DP -> 20., pL0 -> 1.,kon -> 100., koff -> 5., kc -> 5.};

eqns = {diffeqP, diffeqpL, diffeqPpL, condrFar, initP, initpL, initPpL} /. params;

sol = NDSolveValue[eqns, {P, pL, PpL}, {r, z} \[Element] meshD, {t, 0, 10}]
```

I have been looking at solutions using `Plot3D` in a manipulate function. i.e.

```
Manipulate[Plot3D[sol[[1]][r, z, t], {r, dr, rFar}, {z, 0, h}, PlotRange -> {-.00001, .06}], {t, 0, 10, .1}]

Manipulate[Plot3D[sol[[2]][r, z, t], {r, dr, rFar}, {z, 0, h}, PlotRange -> {-.00001, 1.0001}], {t, 0, 10, .1}]

Manipulate[Plot3D[sol[[3]][r, z, t], {r, dr, rFar}, {z, 0, h}, PlotRange -> {-.00001, 1.0001}], {t, 0, 10, .1}]
```

---

**Broken Code**

The issue comes in if I try to keep track of how much of the species "$L$" we have over time. This just involves adding in an additional differential equation and initial condition to our set of equations

```
diffeqL = D[L[r, z, t], t] == kc*PpL[r, z, t];

initL = L[r, z, 0.] == 0.;

eqns = {diffeqP, diffeqpL, diffeqPpL, diffeqL, condrFar, initP, initpL, initPpL, initL} /. params;
```

Then I run the differential equation solver

```
sol = NDSolveValue[eqns, {P, pL, PpL, L}, {r, z} \[Element] meshD, {t, 0, 10}]
```

and I get an error of

> LinearSolve::sing: Matrix SparseArray[<<1>>] is singular.

It seems odd to me that adding in an additional species gives an error. The way I am currently handling "$L$" is similar to (and I would say simpler than) how I handle "$pL$" and "$P\cdot pL$", yet those are being handled fine.

Is there an explicit setting I can change in the differential equation solver to get around this "linear solve" error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`NDSolve` can not always figure out which boundary condition belong to which equation. The issue you are seeing is described in the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementBestPractice.html#898113620). There are two things you can do in this case. One is to rename the dependent variables of your system of PDEs into something that has alphabetical ordering like so:

```
rename = {P -> aa, pL -> bb, PpL -> cc, L -> dd};
eqns = {diffeqP, diffeqpL, diffeqPpL, diffeqL, condrFar, initP, 
     initpL, initPpL, initL} /. rename /. params;
sol2 = NDSolveValue[eqns, 
  rename[[All, 2]], {r, z} \[Element] meshD, {t, 0, 10}]
```

A second approach is to put the `DirichletCondition` into the equation it belongs to, much like the `NeumannValue`:

```
diffeqP2 = 
  D[P[r, z, t], t] - 
    DP*Laplacian[P[r, z, t], {r, \[Theta], z}, "Cylindrical"] + 
    kon*P[r, z, t]*pL[r, z, t] - (koff + kc)*PpL[r, z, t] == 
   NeumannValue[pSource, z == 0] + condrFar;
eqns = {diffeqP2, diffeqpL, diffeqPpL, diffeqL, initP, initpL, 
    initPpL, initL} /. params;
sol = NDSolveValue[
  eqns, {P, pL, PpL, L}, {r, z} \[Element] meshD, {t, 0, 10}]
```

I understand this is very inconvenient and I will try to find a better (automatic) solution for this. Since this issue is also holding back some other FEM projects I'll have to figure this out at some point in time - but it's quite complicated and tricky.... I'll do my best, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Well that is very interesting. I was reading through that page but hadn't hit that section or even recognized its relevance to me here. Thanks for the information. Hopefully I don't hit any other things like this as I build up to my full model. It seems like I will need to be very careful about how I define my equations, coefficients, etc.